# Azure AD - Is it possible to copy/duplicate/clone roles/user/groups between Enterprise Applications?

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

Here is the deal... I'm very, very green on Azure AD, with little to no experience. Yet, I've been tasked to setup some Enterprise applications as follows:

- We have a Drupal site that is set to use SSO through Azure AD.
- The SSO has to be setup for the "Production" and "Staging" environments
- Because of the difference in URLs for each environment (set in the "Set up Single Sign-On with SAML" page), each has its own "Enterprise Application" set in Azure AD.
- The "App roles" (under Active Directory) being provisioned for both environments is identical.
- The "Users and Groups" (under Enterprise Applications) are also identical for both.
- There are over 40 Active Directory groups being used on this site.
- And eventually I will have to repeat the process above for all our other sites (5 so far)
  The question is:
  Can the "App roles" and/or "User and Groups" be cloned/copied/duplicated from one "Enterprise Application" to another? Or do I have to do the job manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the app roles, open the `App Registration` of the source app (`App1`), go to the `Manifest` blade, which is a JSON representation of the various attributes you see in the portal GUI, and copy the values in the `appRoles` key

[image]

Now go to the `Manifest` of your new app(s) (`App2`), and paste the values into the same `appRoles`

[image]

If you go to the `App roles` blade, you'll now see your copied app roles

[image]

Unfortunately you won't be able to copy/paste the users/groups and roles assigned using the portal, but you can do this, and the previous task of copying the app roles, using various PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you very much. This will save me a lot of time.